# CSS not overriding user agent button style

Tags: html, css

Ok it's the first time this occurs to me, i've ever used css locale in my machine for studying and this time it's having a strange behavior (or i think it is).

As i'm trying to style my page the styles are not applying to buttons. I've been searching for lots of fixes to this, like using a reset.css, speeling `<!DOCTYPE html>` right, having `type="text/css"` in my css declaration, etc.

Using inline css works fine, but writing the same code on a css file doesn't have effect, what's strange is that other css like for tables or the rest of the page works.

So apparently i can't overide user-agent-stylesheet button styles.

Here's my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Botões</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="flex-container">
        <li>
          <button class="btn normal">Apertar</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="full">Apertar</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="block">Apertar</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="outlined">Apertar</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="clear">Apertar</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS file:

```
//PAGE:
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#flex-container {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted lightgray;
}

// ================================
button.btn {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this is console output when i run this file

```
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
user agent stylesheet
button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

My files are structured like:

```
|- index.html
|- css folder
   |- custom.css
   |- reset.css
```

And this is what my button is looking like:

[image: Button]

So why can't i override the user agent style if i always done things like this and worked? Is this a new Google Chrome update? Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS comments are invalid. Syntax errors like that usually break whatever properties follow it.

```
//PAGE:
// ================================
```

should be

```
/* Page: */
/* =============================== */
```

Answer (score 2):

As You said **"Using inline css works fine"** however using external stylesheet is not working .  this is because the user agent stylesheet is more powerful than external stylesheet so you need to use `!important` keyword to make the rule the most powerful and this should fix the problem !.

pay attention to your css comments css comments should be like that `/* you comment goes here */`

and also pay attention to your selectors !! in your css you are selecting an element with btn class inside your button `button .btn` use `.btn` class instead